# Applying inline border style to table cells as there are text inputs inside

Tags: html, css

I need to apply a style on some of my **`<td>`** elements in my table, to show them as there are text inputs in those cells. Until now, I was putting an extra **`<div>`** or **`<span>`** into the cell, then I was applying some border, margin, padding styles to those ones. But since I'm using a third party grid component ***(kendo ui)***, this approach causes some performance issues on the browser. So, I need to apply a style directly to the cell element ***(`<td>` element)*** without any extra elements inside.

I could simply give a border style to **`<td>`** element. But the problem is, I need those borders with 3px or 5px inline. Otherwise it would look like just I have table borders on my grid and it would not look like an input.

How can i apply inline borders like 3px padding to a specific **`<td>`** element? Is it possible without javascript?

Here is a screenshot what I currently have.. I require this display, without elements in the cell:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that simply add css style to td elements

https://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/0v0hyt4t/1/

**html**

```
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**css style**

```
  td{
    background-color:#DDD;
    margin:3px;
    padding-left:10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color: #AAA;
    border-radius:5px;
}
td:hover{
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

Comment: In my case, since I won't apply this to all cells, just specific ones, the margin does not give effect on one td cell only. So the borders on that cell still touches the lines. But I added a "display:inline-block" to the style. And the problem solved. Thank you!!